# Find an duplicate items at position in 2d list in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates, position, 2d

I have a 2d list of route numbers and coordinates that I've produced from out of a KML file. The order is 'routenumber','coordinates' e.g.:

```
[['90', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['93', '37.326,19.39,0.0'], ['94', '-110.67,24.395,0.0'], ['95', '-102.154599,17.915081,0.0'], ['96', '-109.177574,25.537,0.0'], ['97', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['98', '55.319,25.506,0.0'], ['911', '54.939206,25.5249,0.0'], ['914', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['915', '54.9169,25.5031,0.0'], ['916', '55.3709,25.35949,0.0'], ['917', '54.939206,25.5249,0.0'], ['920', '56.4641,25.21,0.0'], ['921', '56.4916,25.376,0.0']]
```

For each route in the list I'm trying to find routes with the same coordinates e.g.

```
Output:
54.939206,25.5249,0.0 is seen in 911, 917
54.93920,25.52,0.0 is seen in 90, 97, 914
```

so at a simple level something that can identify duplicates in the second inner? 'column' of

```
[['1','10'],['2','50'],['3','10'],['4','0'],['5','50']]
```

and provide me with:

```
Output:
10 is seen in 1, 3
50 is seen in 2, 5
```

I have tried the following but am now tying myself in knots and wondering if I should be using a dictionary instead. I'm fairly new to python as you can probably tell. Nothing that I can find on the forums here talks about comparing a specific item at a position in a 2d list (which makes me wonder about using a dictionary)

```
for idx, (route,mcoords) in enumerate(endcoordlist):
    #print(idx, route, coords)
    if any(mcoords in coords for idx, (route,coords) in enumerate(endcoordlist)):    
        print(idx, route, coords)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to sushanth for the code. I have adapted it slightly for readability/noobs like me to understand what's going on.

```
for v in endcoordlist:
    if groups.get(v[1]):
        print(v[0]," is a duplicate with coordinates:",v[1])
        groups[v[1]].append(v[0])
    
    else:
        groups[v[1]] = [v[0]]
        print(v[1]," is unique")

for k, v in groups.items():
    print(f"{k} seen in {','.join(v)}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

Declare a `dict` considering coordinates as the `key` & route as list of `values` for the dict.

```
groups = {}

for v in input_:
    if groups.get(v[1]):
        groups[v[1]].append(v[0])
    else:
        groups[v[1]] = [v[0]]

for k, v in groups.items():
    print(f"{k} seen in {','.join(v)}")
```

---

```
54.93920,25.52,0.0 seen in 90,97,914
37.326,19.39,0.0 seen in 93
...
```

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks for getting back to me and so quickly too.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your input list based on the coordinates then you just need to iterate over the sorted list looking for adjacent values that are equal to one  another. This probably won't give you the output format you want but it does demonstrate how you **could** do it. There are probably more elegant ways:-

```
RN = [['90', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['93', '37.326,19.39,0.0'], ['94', '-110.67,24.395,0.0'], ['95', '-102.154599,17.915081,0.0'], ['96', '-109.177574,25.537,0.0'], ['97', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['98', '55.319,25.506,0.0'],
      ['911', '54.939206,25.5249,0.0'], ['914', '54.93920,25.52,0.0'], ['915', '54.9169,25.5031,0.0'], ['916', '55.3709,25.35949,0.0'], ['917', '54.939206,25.5249,0.0'], ['920', '56.4641,25.21,0.0'], ['921', '56.4916,25.376,0.0']]

RNS = sorted(RN, key=lambda x: x[1])
m = set()
for i in range(len(RNS) - 1):
    if RNS[i][1] == RNS[i + 1][1]:
        coord = RNS[i][1]
        m.add(RNS[i][0])
        m.add(RNS[i + 1][0])
    else:
        if len(m) > 0:
            print(coord, m)
            m = set()
if len(m) > 0:
    print(coord, m)
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Another speedy response. I've marked Sushanth's answer as the correct one.